# Program is Big-Endian even though system is Little-Endian

Tags: c, linux, gcc, endianness

Somehow, my program is treating variables as big endian, even though my system is little endian.

When I execute "lscpu | grep Endian", it returns

```
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
```

But when I run a debug gcc (x86_64 linux) executable with following code:

```
int x = 1235213421;
printf("%x", x);
```

It returns 0x499FDC6D, while for little endian it should return 0x6DDC9F49

Comment: Welcome to SO. "while for little endian it should return 0x6DDC9F49" No. This is not what endianess is about. Your program is not at all affected by endianess. `0x6DDC9F49` is same value as `1235213421` in decimal. If you want to learn about endianess, you need to look at the single bytes in memory, not at values in variables.

Comment: `printf` doesn't print the memory contents as is. Instead it interprets the number according the current endianness, and prints it under the normal conventions (most significant digit goes first).

Comment: If you were to read the binary value from a file, for example with `fread(&x, sizeof x, 1, f)` *then* endianness will matter.

Comment: Seems you have misunderstood what endianness is about. It has nothing to do with the values of variables. They are the same on both bit/little endian systems. It's only about how data is stored in memory.

Comment: What should `printf("%x", 0x499FDC6D);` print on both little endian and big endian systems? What should gdb print for x if you have `int x = 0x499FDC6D;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You told `printf` to print an integer so it does so according to the endianess, making the code portable. If you wish to view how the data is stored in memory, you have to do it byte by byte, like this:

```
int x = 1235213421;
unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*)&x;
for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(int); i++)
{
  printf("%.2x", ptr[i]);
}
```